# Load website in iframe dialog, save open and close time, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I found an example that shows how to load a website in an iframe using jquery, [link](http://elijahmanor.com/demos/jqueryuidialogiframe/index.html)
My question is, is it possible to get a timestamp of the opening and closing event of dialog that displays the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inside `.dialog({ })` you can handle the open and close events, and get the current time.

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open for usage examples of those events.